# jit compiler vs reflection

Tags: java, reflection, compiler-construction, jvm

While studying these two keywords, there is a part where I get confused.

The jit compiler interprets or compiles instructions dynamically, that is, line-by-line.

I learned that reflection is necessary in order to run dynamically since Java is a static language.

I don't know the functional difference between the two.
The jit compiler interprets and compiles dynamically, but isn't this act of finding out information such as class type dynamically?

Comment: The JIT does not compile instructions line-by-line, and reflection is only one mechanism that enables runtime type information.

Comment: It seems you are confusing two different things that don't have a lot to do with eachother (JIT compilation and reflection) because in their descriptions, similar words (dynamic, static) were used. Don't let the words "dynamic" and "static" (which are used in different meanings here) confuse you into thinking that JIT compilation and reflection somehow are related.

Comment: 1. Can the interpreter do line-by-line interpretation, and the JIT compiler do and do caching? What if Java uses these two? 2. If so, I've been told that reflection is essential for an interface to know its implementation. Is this true to know the type dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First there are some incorrect statements in your question.

> The JIT compiler interprets or compiles instructions dynamically, that is, line-by-line.

That is incorrect:

1. The JIT compiler compiles code from bytecodes to native code.  It doesn't interpret code.
2. It does it "just in time" (at runtime).  Dynamic is a possible adverb, but it kind of misses the point.  (JIT compilation typically happens just once ...)
3. JIT compilation does not happen "line by line".  The granularity of JIT compilation is an entire method.

Also JIT compilation is *transparent* to the program.  It doesn't change how the program behaves ... apart from making it go faster.

> I learned that reflection is necessary in order to run dynamically since Java is a static language.

That is also incorrect.  Java is dynamic in many respects without reflection.  For example, the Java language supports:

- dynamic typing using type casts, `instanceof`
- dynamic method call dispatching
- dynamic binding via the standard classloaders

and so on.

Reflection allows you to do certain dynamic things that are not practical using conventional Java compiled from (static) source code.  But saying that reflection is **necessary** to do "dynamic" things in Java is incorrect (or circular).

---

In reality, reflection and JIT are unrelated:

- JIT is a technology for implementing the Java language.  It doesn't alter the nature of the language, or what you can do with it.  It is NOT about "dynamic" behavior at all.  Furthermore, it is not a requirement that a Java implementation includes a JIT compiler, and indeed some implementations don't.
- Reflection is a fundamental part of the standard Java class library.  It allows you to do certain "dynamic" things that would be difficult to do with the core Java language.  And it certainly affects the behavior of Java programs.

---

Finally, you will observe that "dynamic" has a wide range of meanings in different contexts.  You need to careful not to conflate the meanings across the contexts.  (Which is not an easy thing for people whose first language is not English ...)

Comment: 1. Can the interpreter do line-by-line interpretation, and the JIT compiler do and do caching? What if Java uses these two?

2. If so, I've been told that reflection is essential for an interface to know its implementation. Is this true to know the type dynamically?

Comment: 1.  No, and no.  (Whatever "do and do caching means" ... )  2.  That's not necessarily true either.  In many circumstances you could figure out which of a set of classes the current one is by using `instanceof`.  (And in theory an OO program doesn't need to know that anyway ...)

Comment: The reason for using the jit compiler is for speed. Existingly, when only the interpreter was used, interpretation was performed on a per-line basis, but it is inefficient to continuously interpret frequently used lines, so I do not prevent interpreting by caching or whether it is used frequently ?

Comment: Isn't it simple to speed up frequently used methods by compiling rather than interpreting them every time? I use this concept as a cache.

Comment: Well that's not cache really means.  (If you (mis-)use the word in that sense, most IT people people won't understand what you are talking about.)  And it doesn't explain what you mean by "do and do".

Comment: And Java interpretters do not interpret line by line.  They never have.  They interpret bytecode instructions.  Maybe you are confusing Java with BASIC.  JIT compilers compile whole methods (not lines) and they do it after the method has been executed a few times.  1)  To justify the overhead of compiling.  2) Once the interpreter has gathered stats for branch prediction, etcetera.

Comment: i See. Thank you. To summarize, JIT compilation compiles a  method that is frequently used as an interpreter, and then calls the compiled line when the  method is called. is this right?

Comment: But seriously, you should be using Google to find articles that explain this stuff, and reading them ... not asking someone to explain it to your personally.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I searched a lot of posts, but each post had a different explanation, and I was so confused about what was right and what was wrong.

Comment: They are quite possibly all correct (or close enough) ... and you are confused by the words that are used.  Especially if you are in the habit of ascribing incorrect meanings to words (like "caching").  I suggest that you look for a good IT dictionary to help you understand  the terminology.